How to increase the font size for content in cells without changing the table size in latex?
I have a very wide table in latex (see extract below, only part of the full code). I'm happy with the aspect ratio of the table but the text in the cells is too small. How can I increase the font size for the content in the table without changing the aspect ratio of the full table?
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
  \caption{Regression Results} 
  \label{Results}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
\footnotesize
\color{black}}
\makeatother
\copyrightbox [b] {
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}l*{6}{D{.}{.}{-3}}:*{6}{D{.}{.}{-3}}:*{6}{D{.}{.}{-3}}}
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable: y}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable: v}}\\
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{without IV}} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textit{with IV}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{First Stage Regression}}\\
\cline{2-19} 
\\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{combined-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Country-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Random Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pooling} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{First Differences} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Country and Time-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Country-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Random Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pooling} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{First Differences} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Country and Time-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Country-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time-Fixed Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Random Effects} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pooling} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{First Differences} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(18)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 X1 & 0.099 & 0.108 & 0.041 & 0.202 & 0.022 & -0.256^{*} & -1.026 & -1.114 & -0.270 & 0.245 & 0.302 & 0.547 & -0.053^{**} & 0.054^{**} & 0.359^{***} & 0.105^{***} & 0.266^{***} & 0.027^{*} \\  
  & (0.178) & (0.185) & (0.108) & (0.123) & (0.117) & (0.151) & (1.072) & (1.084) & (0.197) & (0.363) & (0.238) & (1.157) & (0.021) & (0.024) & (0.055) & (0.021) & (0.050) & (0.015) \\
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 X2 & -0.618^{***} & 0.366^{*} & -0.328 & 0.356 & 0.259 & 0.598^{***} & -0.574^{**} & 0.585^{*} & -0.240 & 0.349 & 0.181 & 0.355 & 0.076 & 0.150 & 0.112 & 0.135 & 0.078 & 0.300^{**} \\ 
  & (0.225) & (0.216) & (0.200) & (0.239) & (0.210) & (0.195) & (0.268) & (0.348) & (0.204) & (0.237) & (0.217) & (0.386) & (0.111) & (0.113) & (0.133) & (0.118) & (0.140) & (0.132) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 X3 & 0.715^{**} & 0.126 & 0.727^{***} & 0.033 & 0.376^{*} & 0.489^{*} & 1.083^{**} & 1.039 & 0.975^{***} & 0.031 & 0.127 & -0.005 & 0.261^{**} & 0.764^{***} & 0.863^{***} & 0.834^{***} & 0.967^{***} & 0.618^{***} \\ 
  & (0.305) & (0.351) & (0.186) & (0.275) & (0.212) & (0.291) & (0.494) & (0.828) & (0.221) & (0.453) & (0.310) & (0.851) & (0.105) & (0.120) & (0.119) & (0.121) & (0.131) & (0.142) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{360} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.569} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.757} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.964} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.882} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.956} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.330} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.487} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.685} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.962} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.832} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.954} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.195} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.560} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.862} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.950} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.854} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.945} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.716} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.496} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.731} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.960} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.876} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.954} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.297} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.400} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.651} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.958} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.824} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.952} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.155} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.485} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.847} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.945} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.846} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.942} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.702} \\ 
F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{25.295$^{***}$ (df = 16; 307)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{63.097$^{***}$ (df = 16; 324)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{511.775$^{***}$ (df = 17; 325)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,563.288$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{435.952$^{***}$ (df = 17; 342)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.951$^{***}$ (df = 16; 323)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{333.746$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{764.324$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8,159.578$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,693.653$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7,086.472$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{120.802$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24.408$^{***}$ (df = 16; 307)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{126.575$^{***}$ (df = 16; 324)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{365.837$^{***}$ (df = 17; 325)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,993.736$^{***}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{343.340$^{***}$ (df = 17; 342)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51.003$^{***}$ (df = 16; 323)} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{18}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular}
}{source: own representation}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}


don't use adjustbox, \resizebox on tables, it makes it impossible to get font sizes consistent with the rest of the document

@DavidCarlisle I've changed it to \resizebox  but I still have the same problem with the font size.

If you increase the font size, the table will grow wider and \resizebox will shrink it and you get back to square one.


Please, always provide MWE, not only code fragment ...
newer scale table, see @David's comments
Page layout is unknown, consequently  you will need to tweak MWE below so that page layout as well table size will allow to place table nicely on a page
please remove all \multicolumn{1}{c}{c}{ ... }, they are superfluous, i.e. they are just a clutter
Instead of simple tabular I would rather use talltblr of tabularray package with libraries booktabs and siunitx˙

Edit (1):

your table is very wide. T shrink it I suggest to take two measures:

in table reduce font size to \scriptsize and to \tiny where is needed (see MWE below)
replace texts in column headers with some abbreviation and add table notes with explanation of their meaning  are to wide.



Edit (2):

removed page number (table overlap it)
area of the two row cells is now limited to X1 to X3 data cells

Considered aforementioned, possible MWE can be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}  % real page layout is unknow
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[hp]
\thispagestyle{empty}   % <---
\scriptsize
\sisetup{
  input-symbols = ( ),
  table-align-text-post = false,
        } 
\SetTblrStyle{note-tag}{font=\bfseries\tiny}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-tag}{default}{\hfill\InsertTblrNoteTag:\ }
\SetTblrStyle{note}{align=right, hang = 5.4em}

    \begin{adjustwidth}{-20mm}{-20mm}  % need to adjusted so, that left/right margin will be  5mm
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Regression Results}, 
  label = {Results},
%
note{Col. Head.:} = {\scriptsize
           \begin{enumerate*}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}:, itemjoin={{;\quad }}]
        \item   Country and Time-Fixed Effects
        \item   Country-Fixed Effects
        \item   Time-Fixed Effects
        \item   Random Effects
        \item   Pooling
        \item   First Differences
        \item   Combined-Fixed Effects
        \item[\textbf{a}]    Combined-Fixed Effects
           \end{enumerate*}},
%
note{*}   = {$p<0.1$},
note{**}  = {$p<0.05$},
note{***} = {$p<0.01$},
%
remark{Source} ={own representation}
                ]{colsep  = 1pt,
                  colspec = {@{} c *{18}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.3{**}}]} @{}},
                  cell{1}{2}  = {c=12}{},
                  cell{1}{14} = {c=6}{},
                     cell{2}{2,8,14}  = {c=6}{},
                    cell{odd[5-V]}{1}  = {r=2}{}, % <---
                  row{1-2} = {guard, font=\itshape},
                  row{3-4} = {guard},
                  row{W-Z} = {guard, mode=text, rowsep=1pt},
                  row{5-V} = {rowsep   = 0pt},
                  row{odd[6]} = {abovesep=0.5ex},                 
                  }
    \toprule
    &   Dependent variable: $y$
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   Dependent variable: $v$    
                                                        &   &   &   &   &                   \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-1]{2-13}
    \cmidrule[l=-1]{14-19}
    &   without IV  5
        &   &   &   &   &   &   with IV 7
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   First Stage Regression  5   
                                                        &   &   &   &   &                   \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-1]{2-7}
    \cmidrule[lr=-1]{8-13}
    \cmidrule[l=-1]{14-19}
    &   CFE\TblrNote{a}
        &   CyFE\TblrNote{2}
            &   TFE\TblrNote{3}
                &   RE\TblrNote{4}
                    &   P\TblrNote{5}
                        &   FD\TblrNote{6}
    &   CTFE\TblrNote{1}
        &   CyFE\TblrNote{2}
            &   TFE\TblrNote{3}
                &   RE\TblrNote{4}
                    &   P\TblrNote{5}
                        &   FD\TblrNote{6}
    &   CTFE\TblrNote{1}
        &   CyFE\TblrNote{2}
            &   TFE\TblrNote{3}
                &   RE\TblrNote{4}
                    &   P\TblrNote{5}
                        &   FD\TblrNote{6}                                            \\
    &   (1)
        &   (2)
            &   (3)
                &   (4)
                    &   (5)
                        &   (6)
    &   (7)
        &   (8)
            &   (9)
                &   (10)
                    &   (11)
                        &   (12)
    &   (13)
        &   (14)
            &   (15)
                &   (16)
                    &   (17)
                        &   (18)                                                        \\
   \midrule
X1  & 0.099     & 0.108     & 0.041     & 0.202     & 0.022     & -0.256\TblrNote{*}
    & -1.026    & -1.114    & -0.270    & 0.245     & 0.302     & 0.547 
    & -0.053\TblrNote{**}   
                & 0.054\TblrNote{**}    
                            & 0.359\TblrNote{***}   
                                        & 0.105\TblrNote{***}   
                                                    & 0.266\TblrNote{***}  
                                                                & 0.027\TblrNote{*}    \\
    & (0.178)   & (0.185)   & (0.108)   & (0.123)   & (0.117)   & (0.151) 
    & (1.072)   & (1.084)   & (0.197)   & (0.363)   & (0.238)   & (1.157) 
    & (0.021)   & (0.024)   & (0.055)   & (0.021)   & (0.050)   & (0.015)               \\


X2 & -0.618\TblrNote{***}  
                & 0.366\TblrNote{*}
                            & -0.328    & 0.356     & 0.259     & 0.598\TblrNote{***} 
    & -0.574\TblrNote{**} 
                & 0.585\TblrNote{*}
                            & -0.240    & 0.349     & 0.181     & 0.355 
    & 0.076     & 0.150     & 0.112     & 0.135     & 0.078     & 0.300\TblrNote{**}    \\ 
    
    & (0.225)   & (0.216)   & (0.200)   & (0.239)   & (0.210)   & (0.195) 
    & (0.268)   & (0.348)   & (0.204)   & (0.237)   & (0.217)   & (0.386) 
    & (0.111)   & (0.113)   & (0.133)   & (0.118)   & (0.140)   & (0.132)               \\ 
 X3 & 0.715\TblrNote{**} 
    & 0.126     & 0.727\TblrNote{***} 
                            & 0.033     & 0.376\TblrNote{*}
                                                    & 0.489\TblrNote{*}
                                                                & 1.083\TblrNote{**} 
    & 1.039     & 0.975\TblrNote{***} 
                            & 0.031     & 0.127     & -0.005    & 0.261\TblrNote{**} 
    & 0.764\TblrNote{***} 
                & 0.863\TblrNote{***} 
                            & 0.834\TblrNote{***} 
                                        & 0.967\TblrNote{***}   & 0.618\TblrNote{***}   \\ 
    & (0.305)   & (0.351)   & (0.186)   & (0.275)   & (0.212)   & (0.291) 
    & (0.494)   & (0.828)   & (0.221)   & (0.453)   & (0.310)   & (0.851) 
    & (0.105)   & (0.120)   & (0.119)   & (0.121)   & (0.131)   & (0.142)               \\ 
    \midrule
Obser.%vations 
    &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   340  
    &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   340  
    &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   360     &   340                 \\ 
R$^{2}$ 
    &   0.569   &   0.757   &   0.964   &   0.882   &   0.956   &   0.330   
    &   0.487   &   0.685   &   0.962   &   0.832   &   0.954   &   0.195   
    &   0.560   &   0.862   &   0.950   &   0.854   &   0.945   &   0.716               \\ 
Adj. R$^{2}$ 
    &   0.496   &   0.731   &   0.960   &   0.876   &   0.954   &   0.297  
    &   0.400   &   0.651   &   0.958   &   0.824   &   0.952   &   0.155  
    &   0.485   &   0.847   &   0.945   &   0.846   &   0.942   &   0.702               \\ 
F Statistic 
    &   {25.295\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}16; 307)$} 
                &   {63.097\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}17; 324)$}  
                            &   {511.775\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}17; 325)$}  
                                        &   {2,563.288\TblrNote{***}} 
                                                    &   {435.952\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}17; 342)$} 
                                                                &   {9.951\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}16; 323)$} 
    &   333.746\TblrNote{***}  
                &   764.324\TblrNote{***}  
                            &   8,159.578\TblrNote{***}  
                                        &   1,693.653\TblrNote{***}  
                                                    &   7,086.472\TblrNote{***}  
                                                                &   120.802\TblrNote{***}  
    &   {24.408\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}16; 307)$}  
                &   {126.575\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}16; 324)$}  
                            &   {365.837\TblrNote{***}\\  \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}17; 342)$}
                                        &   1,993.736\TblrNote{***}  
                                                    &   {343.340\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}17; 342)$} 
                                                                &   {51.003\TblrNote{***}\\ \tiny$(\mathrm{df}{=}16; 323)$}     \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}


As you can see, font size is now bigger and consistent. For bigger font you may consider to split table into two parts (separate for Dependent variable: $y$ and and separate for Dependent variable: $y$). In this case you will be able to increase font size to \small.

OP may even want to split the table into three parts, and (as suggested by the repeating headers) possibly stack those parts vertically back into one table.

@Teepeemm, good point!
